# how to order by descending date-column with month and year in msaccess?

Tags: ms-access-2007, ms-access-2003

I want show order by Monthly New Issues should go from newest top of list, to oldest at bottom of list like November 2049, August 2049, December 2046, October 2046, march 2046,November 2012, October 2012, September 2012…

I tried with following query:

```
select format(newissue,"yyyy"),newissue  from (SELECT distinct format(dateofissue,"mm/yyyy") as newissue from products order by format(dateofissue,"mm/yyyy") )order by format(newissue,"yyyy") desc
```

and got the following result.

```
Query Result   Expected result what i need
------------   ----------------------------
November 2049   November 2049 
August 2049     August 2049
march 2046      December 2046
October 2046    October 2046
December 2046   March 2046
```

please help me ,to get the desired query output.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> select format(newissue,'yyyy') as dateofissue1,newissue as
>   dateofissue2,format(newissue,'mmmm yyyy') as dateofissue3 from (SELECT
>   distinct format(dateofissue,'mm/yyyy') as newissue from products order
>   by format(dateofissue,'mm/yyyy') )order by format(newissue,'yyyy')
>   desc ,format(newissue,'MM') desc

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
select distinct format(dateofissue,"mmmm yyyy")
from products 
order by dateofissue desc
```